# SQL Developer - Switch windows (not tabs)

Tags: sql, sqldeveloper

SqlDeveloper for Windows has a nice feature where you can edit a .sql file, view a table, and see query results simultaneously (ie, divide your screen into 3 'panes', which can each hold an arbitrary number of tabs). for any who don't know, you can accomplish this by dragging a table and creating a rectangle

Does anyone know the keyboard shortcut for switching between the panes in this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to view a list of the different sections of the screen. Each time you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it moves to the next section. If you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> at the same time then it goes backwards. If you are familiar with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut in Windows then this is very similar.

The shortcut is actually a fairly standard convention in Windows programs, e.g. almost all modern browsers use it to switch between tabs.

[image: SQL Developer]

For items that have sub sections (e.g. the tabs in the table editor) you can move between them using the arrow keys.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. however this isn't the solution I was after (though it seems to be the best solution). Ideally, no graphics would pop up and the cursor would switch automatically. i don't want to think about switching to any of the hidden tabs, just the two or three ones automatically. (IMO, this is a great feature for an IDE - I use RStudio's ctl+1 and ctl+2 constantly). The main problem with your proposed solution is that it's faster for me to just use the mouse

Comment: For some editors/tabs you can assign a number to them by pressing Alt + Shift + *n*. Then to switch to them you can press Alt + *n*. However, not all of them support this.